# toString() in object cannot be applied for , IntelliJ idea error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm trying to create a simple Java Class using IntelliJ as my IDE. I'm getting following error:

Error: "toString() in object cannot be applied for".

Code is provided below. It is the `toString()` method that triggers the error.

```
package HBaseIA.TwitBase.model;

public abstract class User {
    public String user;
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //
        return super.toString("<User : %s, %s, %s>", user, name, email);
    }
}
```

Comment: `User` extends `Object`. Have you looked at the methods available on `Object`?  Which `toString()` method on `Object` do you think takes 4 parameters?

Comment: Just `return "<User : " + user + ", " +  name + ", " + email);`

Comment: @azurefrog I've already corrected thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your using `super.toString(params)` which does not exists, instead try:

```
 @Override
public String toString() {
    //
    return String.format("<User : %s, %s, %s>", user, name, email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class User doesn't extend any class, so you don't have a "super" (it extends Object). Looks like you copy/pasted your code from some other class which was a subclass which implemented a toString() method.

Instead, just print your variables directly:

```
// No @override - you aren't overriding
public String toString() {
    return "Use : " + user + ", " + name + ", " + email;
}
```

Comment: `toString()` exists in all classes in java as they all extend Object, therefore, calling `super.toString()` is valid in theory, however him using parameters is the main problem

Comment: `so you don't have a "super" ` Maybe I'm not clear on what you mean by that, but classes that directly extend `Object` absolutely do get to use `super`